# Why isn't my certain part of the input being replaced with the corresponding char?

Tags: java, replace, char

By the way I am a beginner programmer so i don't really know what to do. This is what I tried but it just prints out the input without the letters being replaced.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  class converter {
  public static void main (String [] args){
  char[][] convert = new char [2][10];
  convert [0][0] = 'I' ;
  convert [0][1] = 'Z' ;
  convert [0][2] = 'E' ;
  convert [0][3] = 'A' ;
  convert [0][4] = 'S' ;
  convert [0][5] = 'G' ;
  convert [0][6] = 'L' ;
  convert [0][7] = 'B' ;
  convert [0][8] = 'P' ;
  convert [0][9] = 'O' ;
  convert [1][0] = '1' ;
  convert [1][1] = '2' ;
  convert [1][2] = '3' ;
  convert [1][3] = '4' ;
  convert [1][4] = '5' ;
  convert [1][5] = '6' ;
  convert [1][6] = '7' ;
  convert [1][7] = '8' ;
  convert [1][8] = '9' ;
  convert [1][9] = '0' ;

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     String input = sc.nextLine();
     for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
        input.replace(convert[0][i], convert [1][i]);
     System.out.print(input);

     }
   }
```

Comment: String is immutable, which means you can't change it, which means `input.replace(convert[0][i], convert [1][i]);` has no effect on `input`. However, the `replace` method will return a new String with the changes if you were to assign this String to another String reference, or even the `input` reference, you would see your changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
input = input.replace(convert[0][i], convert [1][i]);
```

Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) (cannot be modified) in Java, the `replace` method does not affect the variable you call it against, but returns a new string with the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

The `String.replace()` function just returns a new string without affecting the string on which it was called. Change `input.replace(convert[0][i], convert [1][i]);` to `input = input.replace(convert[0][i], convert [1][i]);`.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstanding what exactly is `input.replace` doing!. It creates new string, replaces it in the new string and then RETURN new string with replaces char.

This is what you need to do :

```
input = input.replace(convert[0][i], convert [1][i]);
```